# How to make summary report from all open excel workbooks through vba?

Tags: vba, excel, invoice

I have a folder containing same type of workbooks having single sheet i.e an invoice sheet.
       I want a vba code so that i could make a summary report in a new workbook that will copy bill number, customers name, amount etc from each workbook and at the and it will also calculate the total amount.. I hope you have understood  what i mean to say.
       Is there any brilliant mind?

Comment: Great question and something that is DEFINITELY possible with VBA. Two clarifying questions: (1) did you want to combine everything into a single `Worksheet` for reporting out, or were you looking for a single `Workbook` with many `Worksheets` that summarize everything? and (2) what have you tired so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
 Sub GetSheets()
    Path = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Bro i dont want a sheet from all workbooks to be copied in summary workbook but 
      I want cell values like A1, B3 , D10 etc from each workbook's first sheet to be copied into a summary workbook's first sheet. 
   for example - the summary sheet will get Bill number,customers name, amount from first workbook in the row A2 , B2 , C2, respectively and from second workbook into the row A3, B3, C3.

Comment: You can modify this code between the loop for each you can copy the range whatever you want to copy. Some effort you need to also make.

Comment: Your Paths Contains a space and it's FULLY NOT RECOMMENDED. Change `dt kte` !